# Difference between `latexmk -xelatex` and `latexmk -pdfxe`?

Tags: xetex, pdf, latexmk

I am using `latexmk` to generate a set of pdfs using a PowerShell script, and I see there are two options for doing so. I can either use `-xelatex` or `-pdfxe`. Both work and give me the same output, and for the 5 files I'm running it on right now, it's reasonably quick. But the end result will be run on a couple hundred files. Is there a functional difference in how these two commands work? Or are they different names for the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially yes. As stated in the latexmk documentation, the `-xelatex` "option is equivalent to using the following set of options `-pdfxe -dvi- -ps-`."

The `-dvi-` and `-ps-` ensure, for example, that if one of the latexmkrc files happens to have set one or both of the configuration variables `$dvi_mode` or `$postscript_mode` to be non-zero, that setting will be undone.  If you haven't set either of these, the `-xelatex` and`-pdfxe` options are exactly equivalent.

Comment: Thank you, I definitely missed that in the documentation.